# Is this limit solution $-∞$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is this correct?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x^2}-1\right)=-∞$$

Please help me, I don't have the solution and I want to know if I solved it right.

Comment: Try l'Hopital's rule or get rid of the root.

Comment: You don't need the L'Hopoitals' rule. What is the limit of $\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}/x$?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x} = 1.$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x} -x = -\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

I would write
$$\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}-x^2)(\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}+x^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}+x^2}\right)$$
and you will get $$\frac{x\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{6}{x^3}+\frac{10}{x^4}-1\right)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}}+1}$$.
This tends to $-\infty$ if $x$ tends to $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x^2}-1\right) $$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}}-\frac{x^2}{x}\right) $$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{1+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}}-\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{x} $$

$$(0)-(\infty)$$

I guess you can take it from here :)

Answer (score 0):

For $x>6$, $$ x^2<x^2+6x+10<x^2+x^2+x^2<4x^2,$$
hence $$1<\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x} <2.$$
Conclude.